# Highcharts PhantomJS export SVG as base64

Tags: svg, highcharts, export, base64, phantomjs

I have a question regarding generating an SVG instead of an PNG serverside using PhantomJS. I have PhantomJS running as a server and am POSTing JSON to it (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside). I would like to receive an SVG represented as a BASE64 result stream. I am running in some problems however.

I tried both the following requests, but the base64 result would always represent a png file:

```
{"infile":".......", "type":"image/svg+xml"}
```

And:

```
{"infile":".......", "type":"svg"}
```

I do however get a valid svg file when I use the outfile parameter:

```
{"infile":".......", "type":"svg", "outfile":"anActualSVG.svg"}
```

This writes a file to disk, which is not what I am looking for.

Does anyone have some suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove type parameter. Then base64 string should be returned

Comment: But that Base64 string would be an PNG and not a SVG... I would like it to be an SVG

Comment: I see! Unfortunately, you need to edit highcharts-convert.js file - returned SVG parsed to base64. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript) should help you.